# Pandas: transpose and sum by multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, transpose

I have this dataframe:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({
    'user': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    'category1': [2,4,0,9,1,4,6,0,1],
    'category2': [1,0,1,3,2,0,0,9,0],
    'topic1': [3,2,1,4,2,0,0,1,2],
    'topic2': [0,0,7,2,1,4,6,0,0],

})

    user    category1   category2   topic1  topic2
0   1       2           1           3       0
1   2       4           0           2       0
2   3       0           1           1       7
3   4       9           3           4       2
4   5       1           2           2       1
5   6       4           0           0       4
6   7       6           0           0       6
7   8       0           9           1       0
8   9       1           0           2       0
```

It shows how many time users visited different categories and different topics.

I need to count how many times users who visited a certain category also visited a certain topic. So the output should look like:

```
    category    category_count  topic   topic_count
0   category1       27          topic1  13
1   category1       27          topic2  13
2   category2       16          topic1  11
3   category2       16          topic2  10
```

Will appreciate your help!

**UPD:**

I came up with this solution in the end but I still think there should be a more elegant way...

```
categories = ['category1', 'category2']
topics = ['topic1', 'topic2']

l1 = []
l2 = []
l3 = []
l4 = []
for c in categories:
    for t in topics:
        l1.append(c)
        l2.append(test[c].sum())
        l3.append(t)
        l4.append(test[test[c] > 0][t].sum())

d = {'category':l1,
     'category_count':l2,
    'topic':l3,
    'topic_count':l4}

test_new = pd.DataFrame(d)
test_new
```

Comment: `topic1` should be 15.. no? and why do you repeat the types of category and topic?

Comment: test.groupby('category1').topic1.sum()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MultiIndex` by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['category1','category2'],
                                  ['topic1','topic2']])
print (mux)
MultiIndex(levels=[['category1', 'category2'], 
                   ['topic1', 'topic2']],
           codes=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Then get out `user` column - by drop or ceate index:

```
df = test.set_index('user')
#print (df)
```

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by first ans second level:

```
df1 = df.reindex(mux, axis=1, level=0)
print (df1)
     category1        category2       
        topic1 topic2    topic1 topic2
user                                  
1            2      2         1      1
2            4      4         0      0
3            0      0         1      1
4            9      9         3      3
5            1      1         2      2
6            4      4         0      0
7            6      6         0      0
8            0      0         9      9
9            1      1         0      0

df2 = df.reindex(mux, axis=1, level=1)
print (df2)
     category1        category2       
        topic1 topic2    topic1 topic2
user                                  
1            3      0         3      0
2            2      0         2      0
3            1      7         1      7
4            4      2         4      2
5            2      1         2      1
6            0      4         0      4
7            0      6         0      6
8            1      0         1      0
9            2      0         2      0
```

So possible sum values for `categories` and filter by [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) with `sum` for topics:

```
s1 = df1.sum().rename('category_count')
s2 = df2.where(df1.gt(0)).sum().astype(int).rename('topic_count')
```

Last join togehter:

```
df = (pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)
        .rename_axis(('category','topic'))
        .reset_index()
        .sort_index(axis=1))
print (df)
    category  category_count   topic  topic_count
0  category1              27  topic1           13
1  category1              27  topic2           13
2  category2              16  topic1           11
3  category2              16  topic2           10
```

Comment: What I need is to see is how many users who visited category1 visited topic1 and how many topic2. And then the same with category2.

Comment: @aviss - Sorry, not understand. Can you explain more numbers `13, 11, 10` from expected output?

Comment: 27 is how many times users visited category1 (sum of the category1 column), 13 is how many times users also visited topic1 (sum of the topic1 column where the column1 is not zero). And so on. Sorry, it’s confusing!

Comment: @aviss - Now it is close, can you check?

Comment: Yes, this is closer indeed. Now I need two more lines category1 & topic2 and category2 & topic1.

Comment: @aviss - I try find solution and not understand  how is count `11` for last row?

Comment: 11 is how many times users who visited category2 also visited topic1. Or it's a sum of topic1 when category2 is not zero. I'm thinking this might be the easiest way - filtering the dataframe when `category1 != 0` and doing sum() for each topic...